# What are these strange warnings while invoking ggsave?

Tags: r, ggplot2

While invoking ggsave I get the following strange warnings:

```
> ggsave(filename='/Users/bravegag/Dropbox/CV/skills.pdf', width=12, height=6)
  Warning messages:
  1: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
    unknown AFM entity encountered
  2: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
    unknown AFM entity encountered
  3: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
    unknown AFM entity encountered
  4: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
    unknown AFM entity encountered
```

Is there a way to troubleshoot/fix this? I'd rather not share the code if this is enough to diagnose the issue. Note that the plot comes out just perfectly.

UPDATE: These are my dependencies including extrafonts and the issue happens in Mac OS X as well as in Windows.

```
rm(list=ls())                         # clear workspace
library(ggplot2)                      # use ggplot2 library
library(directlabels)
library(scales)
library(extrafont)
library(extrafontdb)

loadfonts(device="pdf",quiet=TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you using the extrafonts package? What platform are you on?

Comment: Well, it pretty clearly has to do with an interaction between ggplot, extrafont (and presumably the underlying grid code). Not sure how much help you'll get without a specific example. The warnings might be spurious, if the plot looks fine.

Comment: I have that sane problem. Did you resolve than?